# GValue initialization/finalization necessity

Tags: c, initialization, glib, finalization

When should I call `g_value_init`/`g_value_reset`?

Currently, I'm using `g_value_init` and `g_value_reset` in all cases, but I want to know  whether it could be sped up.

I know at least that:

- When using objects or boxed types, one definitely needs to call `g_value_reset`, because the GValue could have acquired a reference or duplicated in case of it being a `GBoxed`.
- When using elementary types like `guint` or `gboolean` (without any memory management), the `g_value_reset` call should theoretically be unnecessary, because no memory should be allocated them. I've even read the implementation, and it proves to be true. However, I am worried that the authors could introduce a change and start to allocate some memory (or just do some tracing) and then it would cause a memory leak.

That's all my current research. I would like to broaden it, possibly backed by official documentation references. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current thoughts are mostly correct. `g_value_init()` must always be used to initialise a stack-allocated `GValue`. `g_value_unset()` must be used whenever a `GValue` goes out of scope, to release any type-specific data for it. `g_value_reset()` should be used if you want to reset a `GValue` to the default value — note that for some types this might mean it still points to allocated memory.

`g_value_unset()` is typically used a lot more frequently than `g_value_reset()`.

Answer (score -1):

I dont't know much about this topic, but i googled `g_value_init` and i found these pages of GNOME developer that might be usefull:

https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Generic-values.html#g-value-reset

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Basic-Types.html#gboolean

See if it helps